# Организация базы данных, когда не известно точное количество вводимых данных

Tags: php, mysql

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Пользователь выбирает от 1 до 16 слов, мне нужно добавить их в базу данных  для того, чтобы потом вывести их на главной.

Проблема:
**Как правильно организовать запрос и саму базу ?** На сколько я понимаю, не нужно создавать 16 полей, для абсолютно одинаковых по своей сущности данных (просто одно-два слова), ещё и при условии, что пользователь может выбрать только одно слово, а не все 16.

Comment: Если каждое из слов вам действительно в работе нужно по отдельности то делаете под слова таблицу буквально с двумя полями: id-сущности к которой относится слово и само слово. т.е. каждое из слов кладется отдельной записью

Comment: А если не нужно то, как вариант, можно просто сохранить в одно поле - json_encode(['слово 1', 'слово 2', 'слово 3']) или serialize(['слово 1', 'слово 2', 'слово 3']), и при выводе - json_decode($data['col']) или unserialize($data['col'])  соответственно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структура(класическая структура `много`-`много` ):

```
CREATE TABLE users( 
   id integer,
   name varchar(255)
   primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE words(
   id integer,
   word varchar(255),
   primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE users_x_words(
   user_id integer,
   word_id    integer,
   Primary Key (word_id,user_id), 
   Foreign Key (word_id) REFERENCES words(id),
   Foreign Key (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

Выборка:

```
SELECT *
FROM users_x_words
JOIN words ON users_x_words.word_id = words.id
WHERE users_x_words.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать таблицу `words` с полями `id` и `name`, а в таблицу `users` нужно добавить новый столбец `word_id`.

Если ваша БД реляционная, постарайтесь не хранить в ней JSON.

Comment: Привет, это **StackOverflow на русском**, и в сообществе принято общаться на русском языке. Если требуется помощь с переводом, можно попросить меня.

Comment: pls translate this ^^

Comment: Done. You missed the point though, a **single** user can have **multiple** words selected. That is many-to-many between words and users. Or I didn't quite understand your point, that's possible. I made a more-or-less direct translation.

Comment: I dont know if  is many to many, "что пользователь может выбрать только одно слово".

Comment: Or "Пользователь выбирает от 1 до 16 слов". That goes to OP for clarification then. UPD: ah, I get it now, that's "add many words into the table". You do seem to be correct, yes.